# Default Equality Comparison of Struct Wrapper types C#

Tags: c#, struct, value-type

The C# Reference states that for value types:

> The ValueType.Equals(Object) method overrides Object.Equals(Object)
>   and provides the default implementation of value equality for all
>   value types in the .NET Framework.
>
> If none of the fields of the current instance and obj are reference
>   types, the Equals method performs a byte-by-byte comparison of the two
>   objects in memory. Otherwise, it uses reflection to compare the
>   corresponding fields of obj and this instance.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7(v=vs.110).aspx

As such since int is a value type I would expect that a simple wrapper for an int, would be equal to the int it wrapped, since it is the same on a byte by byte comparison - they both only contain a single int:

```
    public struct Id
    {
        public Id(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
        public int Id { get; }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(new Id(17).Equals(17);
```

But it actually prints false. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [relevant source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs) is:

```
public abstract class ValueType {
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]
    public override bool Equals (Object obj) {
        BCLDebug.Perf(false, "ValueType::Equals is not fast.  "+this.GetType().FullName+" should override Equals(Object)");
        if (null==obj) {
            return false;
        }
        RuntimeType thisType = (RuntimeType)this.GetType();
        RuntimeType thatType = (RuntimeType)obj.GetType();

        if (thatType!=thisType) {
            return false;
        }

        Object thisObj = (Object)this;
        Object thisResult, thatResult;

        // if there are no GC references in this object we can avoid reflection 
        // and do a fast memcmp
        if (CanCompareBits(this))
            return FastEqualsCheck(thisObj, obj);

        FieldInfo[] thisFields = thisType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        for (int i=0; i<thisFields.Length; i++) {
            thisResult = ((RtFieldInfo)thisFields[i]).UnsafeGetValue(thisObj);
            thatResult = ((RtFieldInfo)thisFields[i]).UnsafeGetValue(obj);

            if (thisResult == null) {
                if (thatResult != null)
                    return false;
            }
            else
            if (!thisResult.Equals(thatResult)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

As you can see, it validates that the type of the arguments match before it checks the bytes. Since your type is not an `int`, it'll always return false.

Answer (score 3):

These aren't the same type. Though the text doesn't explicitly say that, the `Equals` method [checks](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/874b694fa31c1ce92491f2191ed4a006c51ae2d4/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ValueType.cs#L34) that they are the same type.

So this would work:

```
new Id(17).Equals(new Id(17));
```

If you want to handle comparison of two different types on your struct, you need to override `Equals` and handle that yourself.

Comment: So the documentation is wrong/ missing something. That's rare for MSDN

Comment: I wouldn't say it's wrong, I think it just made that assumption. The documentation for [ValueType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7(v=vs.110).aspx), which provides the `Equals` implementation for structs, does mention: "true if obj and this instance are the same type and represent the same value; otherwise, false."

Answer (score 0):

In general, the `Equals` method of an object will not consider it equal to any object of any other type, even if both objects would encapsulate the same value.

Because of overloading, the act of passing values of certain types to the Equals methods of other types may cause them to get converted to the same type as the original.  For example, `(16777216.0f).Equals(16777217)` will select the overload `Equals(float)`, convert the `int` value `16777217` into the nearest `float` value (i.e. `16777216.0f`) which will in turn compare equal to `16777216.0f`.  This behavior could be prevented by converting either operand to `object`, as in `((object)16777.216.0f).Equals(16777216)` or `(16777.216.0f).Equals((object)16777216)`, either of which would report a `float` object as unequal to an `int` object (even though they hold the same numerical value).